# Grammar for access to properties and calls to embedded functions

Tags: python, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, ply, parser-generator

I'm writing a grammar for a small interpreter in PLY. The part I am working on and where I am having problems is the one that refers to expressions, since this can contain both access to properties and calls to embedded functions for a vector data type and "native" data types, in addition to calls to functions.

**I have the following rules:**

**1. To access an attribute/attributes of an "object"**

```
def p_acceso_atributo_rec(p):
    'acceso_atrib : acceso_atrib PUNTO ID'


def p_acceso_atributo(p):
    'acceso_atrib : ID PUNTO ID'
```

For example:

```
person.email
person.address.street
```

**2. To access embedded vector functions or variables of native types**

In this case, there are certain "native" functions of the language, for example, toString, toUpperCase, toLowerCase, and certain vector properties, such as length.

```
def p_expr_llamda_funcion(p):
    'expresion : llamada_funcion_obj'

def p_call_embedded_func(p):
    'llamada_funcion_ob : expresion PUNTO embedded_func PAREN_APERTURA PAREN_CIERRE'

def p_embedded_func_names(p):
    '''
    embedded_func : TO_STRING
                  | TO_UPPER_CASE
                  | TO_LOWER_CASE
    '''
```

In this case, the problem is that I should be able to call such functions in "literals" too, for example:

```
true.toString()

100.57.toString()
```

For that reason I have put *expresion* instead of *ID* in the rule.

However, I am not able to recognize an entry like this:

```
const flag : boolean = true;
console.log("valor true: ", flag.toString());
```

And a syntax error occurs:

`Syntax error at token '.', line 2, column 9`

I can't find the problem. Any suggestions?

The complete code is as follows:

```
import re

from ply import *

import ply.yacc as yacc


reserved = {
    # DATA TYPES
    'number': 'NUMBER',
    'float': 'FLOAT',
    'string': 'STRING',
    'boolean': 'BOOLEAN',
    'char': 'CHAR',
    'null': 'NULL',
    # VARIABLES
    'var': 'VAR',
    'const': 'CONST',
    # EMBEDDED FUNCTIONS
    'parseInt': 'PARSE_INT',
    'parseFloat': 'PARSE_FLOAT',
    'toString': 'TO_STRING',
    'toLowerCase': 'TO_LOWER_CASE',
    'toUpperCase': 'TO_UPPER_CASE',
    'typeof': 'TYPE_OF',
    # VECTOR FUNCTIONS
    'push': 'PUSH',
    'pop': 'POP',
    'indexOf': 'INDEX_OF',
    'join': 'JOIN',
    'length': 'LENGTH',
}

tokens = list(reserved.values()) + [
    'ID',
    'LIT_NUMBER',
    'LIT_FLOAT',
    'LIT_STRING',
    'LIT_BOOLEAN',
    'LIT_CHAR',
    'ASIGNACION',
    'PUNTO',
    'DOS_PUNTOS',
    'PUNTO_COMA',
    'COMA',
    'PLUS',
    'MENOS',
    'MULTI',
    'DIV',
    'MOD',
    'INCREMENTO',
    'DECREMENTO',
    'PAREN_APERTURA',
    'PAREN_CIERRE',
    'LLAVE_APERTURA',
    'LLAVE_CIERRE',
    'CORCHETE_APERTURA',
    'CORCHETE_CIERRE',
    'IGUAL',
    'DIFERENTE',
    'MENOR_QUE',
    'MAYOR_QUE',
    'MENOR_IGUAL',
    'MAYOR_IGUAL',
    'AND',
    'OR',
    'NOT',
    'INTERROGACION',
    'FLECHA',
]

t_ASIGNACION = r'='
t_PUNTO = r'\.'
t_DOS_PUNTOS = r':'
t_PUNTO_COMA = r';'
t_COMA = r','
t_PLUS = r'\+'
t_MENOS = r'-'
t_MULTI = r'\*'
t_DIV = r'/'
t_MOD = r'%'
t_INCREMENTO = r'\+='
t_DECREMENTO = r'-='
t_PAREN_APERTURA = r'\('
t_PAREN_CIERRE = r'\)'
t_LLAVE_APERTURA = r'{'
t_LLAVE_CIERRE = r'}'
t_CORCHETE_APERTURA = r'\['
t_CORCHETE_CIERRE = r'\]'
t_IGUAL = r'=='
t_DIFERENTE = r'!='
t_MENOR_QUE = r'<'
t_MAYOR_QUE = r'>'
t_MENOR_IGUAL = r'<='
t_MAYOR_IGUAL = r'>='
t_AND = r'&&'
t_OR = r'\|\|'
t_NOT = r'!'
t_INTERROGACION = r'\?'
t_FLECHA = r'->'


def t_LIT_FLOAT(t):
    r'([1-9][0-9]*|0)\.[0-9]+'
    try:
        t.value = float(t.value)
    except ValueError:
        t.value = 0.0
    return t


def t_LIT_NUMBER(t):
    r'[1-9]\d*|0'
    try:
        t.value = int(t.value)
    except ValueError:
        t.value = 0
    return t


def t_LIT_BOOLEAN(t):
    r'true|false'
    try:
        if t.value == 'true':
            t.value = True
        elif t.value == 'false':
            t.value = False
    except ValueError:
        t.value = False
    return t


def t_LIT_STRING(t):
    r'"([^\\"]|(\\.))*?"'
    t.value = t.value[1:-1]
    return t


def t_LIT_CHAR(t):
    r"'([^\\']|(\\.))'"
    t.value = t.value[1:-1]
    return t


def t_ID(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
    t.type = reserved.get(t.value, 'ID')
    return t


def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)


def t_COMENTARIO_ML(t):
    r'/\*(.|\n)*?\*/'
    t.lexer.lineno += t.value.count('\n')


def t_COMENTARIO_UL(t):
    r'(//.*?(\n|$))'


t_ignore = ' \t'


def find_column(input_text, lexpos):
    last_cr = input_text.rfind('\n', 0, lexpos)
    if last_cr < 0:
        last_cr = 0
    column = (lexpos - last_cr) + 1
    return column


def t_error(t):
    print(f'Carácter no reconocido: "{t.value[0]}"')
    t.lexer.skip(1)


lexer = lex.lex(reflags=re.UNICODE | re.VERBOSE)

precedence = (
    ('left', 'OR'),
    ('left', 'AND'),
    ('left', 'IGUAL', 'DIFERENTE'),
    ('left', 'MENOR_QUE', 'MAYOR_QUE', 'MENOR_IGUAL', 'MAYOR_IGUAL'),
    ('left', 'PLUS', 'MENOS'),
    ('left', 'MULTI', 'DIV', 'MOD'),
    ('right', 'NOT', 'UMENOS'),
    ('right', 'CORCHETE_APERTURA'),
)


def p_axioma(p):
    'axioma : instrucciones_glob'
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_instrucciones_glob_rec(p):
    'instrucciones_glob : instrucciones_glob instruccion'
    if p[1] is None:
        p[1] = []
    if p[2] is not None:
        p[1].append(p[2])
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_instrucciones_glob(p):
    'instrucciones_glob : '


def p_instruccion(p):
    '''
    instruccion : declaracion PUNTO_COMA
                | asignacion PUNTO_COMA
                | llamada_funcion PUNTO_COMA
    '''
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_declaracion(p):
    'declaracion : VAR ID DOS_PUNTOS tipo_dato'


def p_declaracion_valor(p):
    'declaracion : VAR ID DOS_PUNTOS tipo_dato ASIGNACION expresion'


def p_declaracion_const(p):
    'declaracion : CONST ID DOS_PUNTOS tipo_dato ASIGNACION expresion'


def p_declaracion_vect(p):
    'declaracion : VAR ID DOS_PUNTOS tipo_dato CORCHETE_APERTURA CORCHETE_CIERRE ASIGNACION CORCHETE_APERTURA lista_expr CORCHETE_CIERRE'


def p_declaracion_vect_const(p):
    'declaracion : CONST ID DOS_PUNTOS tipo_dato CORCHETE_APERTURA CORCHETE_CIERRE ASIGNACION CORCHETE_APERTURA lista_expr CORCHETE_CIERRE'


def p_declaracion_vect_copia(p):
    'declaracion : VAR ID DOS_PUNTOS tipo_dato CORCHETE_APERTURA CORCHETE_CIERRE ASIGNACION ID'


def p_declaracion_vect_copia_const(p):
    'declaracion : CONST ID DOS_PUNTOS tipo_dato CORCHETE_APERTURA CORCHETE_CIERRE ASIGNACION ID'


def p_declaracion_interface(p):
    'declaracion : VAR ID DOS_PUNTOS ID ASIGNACION LLAVE_APERTURA def_atributos LLAVE_CIERRE'


def p_def_atributos_rec(p):
    'def_atributos : def_atributos ID DOS_PUNTOS expresion PUNTO_COMA'
    if p[1] is None:
        p[1] = []
    p[1].append((p[2], p[4]))
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_def_atributos(p):
    'def_atributos : ID DOS_PUNTOS expresion PUNTO_COMA'
    p[0] = [(p[1], p[3])]


def p_acceso_atributo_rec(p):
    'acceso_atrib : acceso_atrib PUNTO ID'


def p_acceso_atributo(p):
    'acceso_atrib : ID PUNTO ID'


def p_lista_atrib_rec(p):
    'lista_atrib : lista_atrib ID DOS_PUNTOS tipo_interface PUNTO_COMA'


def p_lista_atrib(p):
    'lista_atrib : ID DOS_PUNTOS tipo_interface PUNTO_COMA'


def p_tipo_interface_u(p):
    'tipo_interface : ID'


def p_tipo_interface(p):
    'tipo_interface : tipo_dato'


def p_asignacion(p):
    'asignacion : ID ASIGNACION expresion'


def p_asignacion_incr(p):
    'asignacion : ID INCREMENTO expresion'


def p_asignacion_decr(p):
    'asignacion : ID DECREMENTO expresion'


def p_asignacion_vect_matriz(p):
    'asignacion : ID lista_acceso ASIGNACION expresion '


def p_llamada_funcion_instr(p):
    'llamada_funcion : ID PAREN_APERTURA lista_expr PAREN_CIERRE'


def p_call_embedded_func(p):
    'llamada_funcion_obj : expresion PUNTO embedded_func PAREN_APERTURA PAREN_CIERRE'


def p_embedded_func_names(p):
    '''
    embedded_func : TO_STRING
                  | TO_UPPER_CASE
                  | TO_LOWER_CASE
    '''


def p_lista_instr_bloque_rec(p):
    'lista_instr_bloque : lista_instr_bloque instr_bloque'
    if p[1] is None:
        p[1] = []
    if p[2] is not None:
        p[1].append(p[2])
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_lista_instr_bloque(p):
    'lista_instr_bloque : '


def p_instr_bloque(p):
    '''
    instr_bloque : declaracion PUNTO_COMA
                 | asignacion PUNTO_COMA
                 | llamada_funcion PUNTO_COMA
    '''
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_tipo_dato(p):
    '''
    tipo_dato : NUMBER
              | FLOAT
              | CHAR
              | BOOLEAN
              | STRING
    '''


def p_lista_expr_rec(p):
    'lista_expr : expresion'
    p[0] = [p[1]]


def p_lista_expr(p):
    'lista_expr : lista_expr COMA expresion'
    if p[1] is None:
        p[1] = [p[3]]
    else:
        p[1].append(p[3])
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_lista_expr_vacia(p):
    'lista_expr : '
    p[0] = []


def p_expresion_binaria(p):
    '''
    expresion : expresion PLUS expresion
              | expresion MENOS expresion
              | expresion MULTI expresion
              | expresion DIV expresion
              | expresion MOD expresion
              | expresion IGUAL expresion
              | expresion DIFERENTE expresion
              | expresion MENOR_QUE expresion
              | expresion MAYOR_QUE expresion
              | expresion MENOR_IGUAL expresion
              | expresion MAYOR_IGUAL expresion
              | expresion AND expresion
              | expresion OR expresion
    '''


def p_expr_agrupada(p):
    'expresion : PAREN_APERTURA expresion PAREN_CIERRE'


def p_expresion_unaria(p):
    '''
    expresion : MENOS expresion %prec UMENOS
              | NOT expresion
    '''


def p_expr_id(p):
    'expresion : ID'


def p_expr_acceso_vect_mat(p):
    'expresion : ID lista_acceso'


def p_expr_llamda_funcion(p):
    'expresion : llamada_funcion_obj'


def p_lista_acceso_dims_rec(p):
    'lista_acceso : lista_acceso CORCHETE_APERTURA expresion CORCHETE_CIERRE'


def p_acceso_dim(p):
    'lista_acceso : CORCHETE_APERTURA expresion CORCHETE_CIERRE'


def p_expresion_literal(p):
    'expresion : literal'


def p_expresion_llamada_func(p):
    'expresion : ID PAREN_APERTURA lista_expr PAREN_CIERRE'


def p_expr_parse_int(p):
    'expresion : PARSE_INT PAREN_APERTURA expresion PAREN_CIERRE'


def p_expr_parse_float(p):
    'expresion : PARSE_FLOAT PAREN_APERTURA expresion PAREN_CIERRE'


def p_expr_type_of(p):
    'expresion : TYPE_OF expresion'


def p_expr_acceso_atributo(p):
    'expresion : acceso_atrib'


def p_literal(p):
    '''
    literal : LIT_NUMBER
            | LIT_FLOAT
            | LIT_CHAR
            | LIT_BOOLEAN
            | LIT_STRING
    '''


def p_error(p):
    if p:
        print(f'Error sintáctico: {p.type}')
        print("Syntax error at token '%s', line %s, column %s" % (
            p.value, p.lineno, find_column(p.lexer.lexdata, p.lexpos)))
        parser.errok()
    else:
        print('Syntax error at EOF')


parser = yacc.yacc(debug=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    archivo_entrada = open('Embebidas.olc')

    entrada = archivo_entrada.read()

    lexer.input(entrada)

    instrucciones = parser.parse(entrada)
```

Comment: Three tips: (1) use `import regex as re` (faster and more features); (2) use sly instead of ply (more uptodate, multiple improvements); (3) activate sly debugging.
Did you verify there are no shift/reduce and reduce/reduce conflicts? Especially reduce/reduce can not be ignored. See: https://sly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sly.html#parser-debugging